# Node-Webkit's (nwjs) node-remote Usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit

I wonder if someone can give me an example about how "node-remote" works if I want to run some of the logic/functions of my application from the server.

Like, I don't know what to do after adding "node-remote" : "hostip" into package.json, what should my server provide? .js file that has the functions I want to run? So is it like: "node-remote" : "myappserver.com/funcs.js" ? I am so confused about this...

I can't find enough information on web about this, so some help or at least a better explanation of "baconface"'s reply from this link would be so helpful: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-remote` is used for to expose node.js + nw.gui APIs for html script tags and javascript files coming from your website. That's it! You can use `require`, objects like `global`, `process` in these files.

`node-remote` parameter itself expects a domain name or ip address of hosts you want nw.js to allow to use node.js APIs for these hosts while other hosts can't access them.

Little example:

1. configure simple `package.json` and set `node-remote` parameter to `github.com` on it.
2. save `package.json`.
3. open `nw` application.
4. open page `https://github.com/` on it.
5. open `Developer Tools`.
6. in console type `require('fs').writeFileSync('test.txt', 'Hello, World!');` and hit enter.

Now you should see `test.txt` file in nw's root directory.

7. delete `test.txt`.
8. edit your `package.json` and remove `node-remote` field.
9. repeat [2..6] actions.

Now you should see error like `"require" is undefined` in DevTools console

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Sicne this has been posted "node-remote" has change slightly.  Here is an example:

```
"node-remote": "*://*",
```

**Direct Links:**

- Notes about changes from v0.12 to v0.13 - http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Migration/From%200.12%20to%200.13/
- Formatting of "node-remote": http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#node-remote