# How can I run scripts in served pages in NW.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js

I am trying to use nw.js to package a desktop application. 
the application navigates to pages that are being served from a xampp server on the same computer that the application will be running on.

When nw.js navigates to the page via file:// the scripts load succesfully.

When it navigates via http:// the scripts do not load.

the error in the console is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How can I remedy this? I need it to load via http since the app uses php for a several essential functions.

Comment: You should allow it through manifest. https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/manifest-format#node-remote

Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295404/node-webkits-nwjs-node-remote-usage

Comment: `via http://` do you have the correct host name?

Comment: @Fella That was is. I used node-remote based on a comment I saw on another site but it failed so hard I got a headache. I looked at the page you sent and it clarified what I saw on the other page:
    https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/2679

Post you answer and I'll mark it as correct.

I had to set the property as "node-remote" : "127.0.0.1"

Comment: @JaromandaX I did but I did not set it in the manifest correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with node-remote.

package.json

```
{
  "main": "http://localhost:3030/",
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "description": "demo app of node-webkit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "node-remote" : "localhost:3030",
  "window": {
    "title": "node-webkit demo",
    "toolbar": true,
    "frame": true,
    "position": "center"
  }
}
```

html file on localhost

```
<script>document.write(require, process);</script>
```

nwjs (v0.12.3) app output

> function (name) { if (name == 'nw.gui') return nwDispatcher.requireNwGui(); return global.require(name); }[object process]