# Require Node JS core modules from subdirectories (in NW JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, nwjs

I am absolutely clueless about the method to be used to require a Node JS core module in sub-directories of the root folder.
I have an app with a page in a sub-directory where I need to require the File System module of Node JS. The file system (fs) module is not found in the `node_modules` folder in the root directory and hence, I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work. (The page and the script requiring 'fs' module runs well when placed in the root directory, but not otherwise.)

---

I have also tried adding: `"homepage": "./",` to package.json which seemed to work initially, but after a change of directories, it stopped working.

It also seems to not work in files other than the main file in the document root.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ax-net",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index-main.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nw .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nw": "^0.46.4-sdk"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  }
}
```

---

Index-main.html redirects to another file named index.html through `window.open('index.html');`

This is the head of my index.html which loads the script `norm.js` which contains the `require`:

```html
<head>
    <title>
        cs | xx xx 2020
    </title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/home/aakash/ax-net/x/samples/icons/ax.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="file:///home/aakash/ax-net/x/samples/css/v2/cs.css" />
    <script src="norm.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is my `norm.js`:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
function histforward() {
        history.go(+1);
        //alert("done");
}
function histbackward() {
        history.go(-1);
        //alert("done");
}
function reload() { 
        //Refresh the current page.
        window.location.reload(false); //False for soft refresh
        //alert("done");
}
function edit() {
    let exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var location = process.cwd() + "/" + (document.URL).replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    exec("code "+ location);
}
function directory() {
    var location = process.cwd();
    window.location.href=location;
}
function read(file, id) {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=data.toString();
    //alert(data.toString()); 
    })
}
```

My Dev Tools Console Log of the NW JS window is:
[image: console log]

#### Currently all of these are in the root directory, but still fs only seems to work when the page requiring it (index.html) is set as the main page of the app. It doesn't work when the page is redirected to from another page.

From the searches that I performed, I thought it has got something to do with the document root and the `"homepage": "",` entry in package.json.

---

**UPDATE-1**

I found a partial solution to my problem here :

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3359

and here:

[Node-Webkit's (nwjs) node-remote Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295404/node-webkits-nwjs-node-remote-usage)

So, I added the following to my `package.json`:

```
"homepage": "./",
"node-remote": "*://*",
```

Now, the `index.html` page in root directory seem to work fine (upon being redirected to, from the main page of the app), but the same `index.html` when buried in a sub-directory gives the following errors in Console Logs:
[image]

---

**UPDATE-2**

NOTE: (For clarification) I am running my app using the command `npm start`, I am using NW JS to run it which like electron uses NodeJS.

NOTE-2 (for the query by Ahmed): running `const fs = require('fs'); console.log(fs);` through `node` in terminal gives the following output:

```
{
  appendFile: [Function: appendFile],
  appendFileSync: [Function: appendFileSync],
  access: [Function: access],
  accessSync: [Function: accessSync],
  chown: [Function: chown],
  chownSync: [Function: chownSync],
  chmod: [Function: chmod],
  chmodSync: [Function: chmodSync],
  close: [Function: close],
  closeSync: [Function: closeSync],
  copyFile: [Function: copyFile],
  copyFileSync: [Function: copyFileSync],
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream],
  createWriteStream: [Function: createWriteStream],
  exists: [Function: exists],
  existsSync: [Function: existsSync],
  fchown: [Function: fchown],
  fchownSync: [Function: fchownSync],
  fchmod: [Function: fchmod],
  fchmodSync: [Function: fchmodSync],
  fdatasync: [Function: fdatasync],
  fdatasyncSync: [Function: fdatasyncSync],
  fstat: [Function: fstat],
  fstatSync: [Function: fstatSync],
  fsync: [Function: fsync],
  fsyncSync: [Function: fsyncSync],
  ftruncate: [Function: ftruncate],
  ftruncateSync: [Function: ftruncateSync],
  futimes: [Function: futimes],
  futimesSync: [Function: futimesSync],
  lchown: [Function: lchown],
  lchownSync: [Function: lchownSync],
  lchmod: undefined,
  lchmodSync: undefined,
  link: [Function: link],
  linkSync: [Function: linkSync],
  lstat: [Function: lstat],
  lstatSync: [Function: lstatSync],
  mkdir: [Function: mkdir],
  mkdirSync: [Function: mkdirSync],
  mkdtemp: [Function: mkdtemp],
  mkdtempSync: [Function: mkdtempSync],
  open: [Function: open],
  openSync: [Function: openSync],
  opendir: [Function: opendir],
  opendirSync: [Function: opendirSync],
  readdir: [Function: readdir],
  readdirSync: [Function: readdirSync],
  read: [Function: read],
  readSync: [Function: readSync],
  readv: [Function: readv],
  readvSync: [Function: readvSync],
  readFile: [Function: readFile],
  readFileSync: [Function: readFileSync],
  readlink: [Function: readlink],
  readlinkSync: [Function: readlinkSync],
  realpath: [Function: realpath] { native: [Function] },
  realpathSync: [Function: realpathSync] { native: [Function] },
  rename: [Function: rename],
  renameSync: [Function: renameSync],
  rmdir: [Function: rmdir],
  rmdirSync: [Function: rmdirSync],
  stat: [Function: stat],
  statSync: [Function: statSync],
  symlink: [Function: symlink],
  symlinkSync: [Function: symlinkSync],
  truncate: [Function: truncate],
  truncateSync: [Function: truncateSync],
  unwatchFile: [Function: unwatchFile],
  unlink: [Function: unlink],
  unlinkSync: [Function: unlinkSync],
  utimes: [Function: utimes],
  utimesSync: [Function: utimesSync],
  watch: [Function: watch],
  watchFile: [Function: watchFile],
  writeFile: [Function: writeFile],
  writeFileSync: [Function: writeFileSync],
  write: [Function: write],
  writeSync: [Function: writeSync],
  writev: [Function: writev],
  writevSync: [Function: writevSync],
  Dir: [Function: Dir],
  Dirent: [Function: Dirent],
  Stats: [Function: Stats],
  ReadStream: [Getter/Setter],
  WriteStream: [Getter/Setter],
  FileReadStream: [Getter/Setter],
  FileWriteStream: [Getter/Setter],
  _toUnixTimestamp: [Function: toUnixTimestamp],
  F_OK: 0,
  R_OK: 4,
  W_OK: 2,
  X_OK: 1,
  constants: [Object: null prototype] {
    UV_FS_SYMLINK_DIR: 1,
    UV_FS_SYMLINK_JUNCTION: 2,
    O_RDONLY: 0,
    O_WRONLY: 1,
    O_RDWR: 2,
    UV_DIRENT_UNKNOWN: 0,
    UV_DIRENT_FILE: 1,
    UV_DIRENT_DIR: 2,
    UV_DIRENT_LINK: 3,
    UV_DIRENT_FIFO: 4,
    UV_DIRENT_SOCKET: 5,
    UV_DIRENT_CHAR: 6,
    UV_DIRENT_BLOCK: 7,
    S_IFMT: 61440,
    S_IFREG: 32768,
    S_IFDIR: 16384,
    S_IFCHR: 8192,
    S_IFBLK: 24576,
    S_IFIFO: 4096,
    S_IFLNK: 40960,
    S_IFSOCK: 49152,
    O_CREAT: 64,
    O_EXCL: 128,
    UV_FS_O_FILEMAP: 0,
    O_NOCTTY: 256,
    O_TRUNC: 512,
    O_APPEND: 1024,
    O_DIRECTORY: 65536,
    O_NOATIME: 262144,
    O_NOFOLLOW: 131072,
    O_SYNC: 1052672,
    O_DSYNC: 4096,
    O_DIRECT: 16384,
    O_NONBLOCK: 2048,
    S_IRWXU: 448,
    S_IRUSR: 256,
    S_IWUSR: 128,
    S_IXUSR: 64,
    S_IRWXG: 56,
    S_IRGRP: 32,
    S_IWGRP: 16,
    S_IXGRP: 8,
    S_IRWXO: 7,
    S_IROTH: 4,
    S_IWOTH: 2,
    S_IXOTH: 1,
    F_OK: 0,
    R_OK: 4,
    W_OK: 2,
    X_OK: 1,
    UV_FS_COPYFILE_EXCL: 1,
    COPYFILE_EXCL: 1,
    UV_FS_COPYFILE_FICLONE: 2,
    COPYFILE_FICLONE: 2,
    UV_FS_COPYFILE_FICLONE_FORCE: 4,
    COPYFILE_FICLONE_FORCE: 4
  },
  promises: [Getter]
}
undefined
```

---

Update-3) This may be helpful: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/7183

Comment: As you said, `fs` is a core module. It is not in the `node_modules` folder, which contains only additional modules that you installed for your project. `require("fs")` is all you need.

Comment: Yes I know that fs is core module, but `const fs = require('fs')` only seems to work in the root directory where `node_modules` folder is located...

Comment: for all other html pages in subdirectories which require fs, it simply doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please add your folder strucute and add some code ?!

Comment: What's your Node version? Did you try reinstalling it? `require("fs")` should work anyhere, as it is a global module

Comment: Yes I tried re-installing it. My Nw Js version is: 0.46.4 I guess.

Comment: Node.js code is not supposed to work in the browser, but that is exactly what you are trying to do. I am not sure how you got it to work at first, but it should not, unless you are using webpack or something similar.